# Display scp progress in zenity window

Tags: linux, bash, file-transfer, progress-bar, zenity

I would like to graphically display the scp transfer progress of several files from a remote server to the local machine.

I thought using Zenity for example. Browsing the net I found the command pv can be used to do so.

Something like that:

```
(
scp user@remote:/home/folder/* . | pv -n -b -s $totalSize
) | zenity --progress --title="Transfer window" --percentage=0 --auto-close
```

But this doesn't work.

Using rsync could be an alternative.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, scp doesn't display progress if stdout is not a terminal.

You have 2 options:

*Option 1* modify scp code to ignore the stdout not being a terminal.
Download sources (from http://www.openssh.com/)

Comment the following code in scp.c:main()

```
if (!isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
    showprogress = 0;
```

*Option 2* Using a wrapper, fool scp to think that there is a terminal.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char **argv) {
 int fd;
 pid_t pid;
 char c,c1,c2;

 if (argc != 3) {
  printf("usage: [[user@]host1:]file1 [[user@]host2:]file2\n\nThis is a program that wraps scp and prints out the numeric progress on separate lines.\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  _exit(1);
 }

 pid = forkpty (&fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
 if (pid == 0) {
  execlp ("scp", "scp", argv[1], argv[2], (char *) NULL);
  _exit (1);
 } else if (pid == -1) {
  return 1;
 } else {
  FILE *F;

  F = fdopen (fd, "r");

  //reading character by character isn't horribly efficient...
  while((c = fgetc(F)) != -1) {
   if (c == '%') {
    if (c1 == ' ')
     printf("%c\n", c2);  //one digit progess
    else if (c1 == '0' && c2 == '0')
     printf("100\n"); //done
    else
     printf("%c%c\n", c1,c2); //two digit progress
   }
   fflush(stdout);
   c1 = c2;
   c2 = c;                   
  }

 fflush (F);
 wait (0);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Compile the wrapper and use it to scp

```
 $ ./scpwrap /home/ubuntu/somefile user@example.com:~ | zenity --progress
```

Original solution & more details from: http://blog.clay.shep.me/2009/06/showing-scp-progress-using-zenity.html

Comment: Can you include the relevant information from the link here?

Comment: The solution is not a short one to explain. The author of the post has done a great job of explaining. I can try to explain but it is better to visit the link.

Comment: As good as a resource is, it might change/disappear at any time, so all the more reason reason to include the information here- and [link only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) in any case.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for the info. If i have a contributing answer i would probably contribute in future. For this question, Would you recommend copy pasting the solution? As a new contributor, I find negative scores for pointing to a solution to be discouraging.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, so I can't tell you why they did that. But to address your question: copying and pasting an entire article isn't appropriate, but quoting parts and summarising others parts would be.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the fact that zenity expects numbers and comments, one by line. You're sending more with the "-b" flag. Try removing it and try again.

> Zenity reads data from standard input line by line. If a line is prefixed with #, the text is updated with the text on that line. If a line contains only a number, the percentage is updated with that number.

See: [Zenity documentation](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/progress.html.en)

**Using SCP alone**

Now, it seems like you want to have some sort of progession view. I'd try the verbose flag of scp which should do the trick:

```
scp -v user@remote:/home/folder/* .
```

I'm not sure of what you're trying to accomplish there but you might want to include subfolders in your copy command and compression to cut down transfer times like so:

```
scp -vrC user@remote:/home/folder/* .
```

**Using Rsync**

If I were you, I'd use rsync for that, which makes incremental copies and many more stuff like keeping permissions and times. Here's some commands I use all the time:

*Incremental copy without removing local files*

```
rsync -avz --progress user@remote:/home/folder/ ./
```

*Incremental copy making a mirror of both directories, deleting files not present on remote server*

```
rsync -avz --delete --progress user@remote:/home/folder/ ./
```